# Angular 8 Express Post Throws a CORs Error

Tags: node.js, angular, cors

Yes I know you can normally fix these by setting the origin wilcard to '*' but I'm using "credentials : true", so that's thrown my normal solution out the window.

The Issue I'm having is that when I try to perform a post request to Express, it seems to first submit as an OPTIONS, then get redirected as GET, then redirected again as POST.

All my "Access-Control-Allow-XXXX" headers appear in the original OPTIONS but then gets lost in the redirects.

The error being shown from the browser is;

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4200/' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/api/save') from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Here's my express cors setup, the dynamic origin was set because I thought the direct might have been looking for the API address as a possible origin, and then undefined and null because I got annoyed with it;

```
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

whitelist = [UI_BASE_URL, API_BASE_URL, undefined, null];

app.use(
  cors({
    allowedHeaders: [
      'Origin',
      'X-Requested-With',
      'Content-Type',
      'Accept',
      'X-Access-Token',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'
    ],
    preflightContinue: false,
    credentials: true,
    origin: function(origin, callback) {
      if (whitelist.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
        callback(null, true);
      } else {
        callback(new Error('Not allowed by CORS'));
      }
    },
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  })
);
```

And here's the service call from angular

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
  }),
};

save(myData): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(
      this.workSpaceReportURL + 'save',
      {
        data: myData,
        withCredentials: true,
      },
      httpOptions
    );
  }
```

and because they might be useful, the request and response headers from the POST.

RESPONSE

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 43
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Date: Mon, 11 Nov 2019 14:50:31 GMT
Expires: 0
Location: http://localhost:4200
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: connect.sid=s%3Aj3wYyE_I14o6b_C-L6EDnOxesW0CBVks.WEwBNiQegZ1ufG2d40%2BF4BGfbCWPbOz9FS4Kj%2BC14Pc; Path=/; Expires=Mon, 18 Nov 2019 13:30:31 GMT; HttpOnly
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains
Surrogate-Control: no-store
Vary: Origin, Accept
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 184
Content-Type: application/json
Host: localhost:3000
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/data-controller
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36
```

I've tried a number of different solutions I've come across on SO but they normally end up being fixed by the usual wildcard origin.

Thanks for any suggestions you can make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I realised what the solution was. I'd just spent so long starting at it to realise.

I'd managed to strip out the Content-Type without noticing, and was passing the withCredentials in as part of the body, not the httpOptions (which I tihnk was my original problem).

In case it helps someone else out a few years from now, the httpOptions and post should've looked like the below.

I'm now going to go stand in the server room of shame.

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }),
  withCredentials: true,
};

save(myData): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(
      this.workSpaceReportURL + 'save',
      {
        myData,
      },
      httpOptions
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you used an old way to add cord headers. Have you tried doing this?

```
var cors = require('cors')

app.use(cors())
```

Make sure to run the last one before you run your other app.use

Comment: Hi TK, thanks for replying. If I strip it back to app.use(cors()) I get "The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'". As a minimum I need origin due to credentials.

Comment: I believe that means you just can't because of safety issues. Please try to use the protocol + domain + port you used, which would be http://localhost:4200 it looks like.
This should work. ```app.use(cors({
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200'
}));```

Comment: Thanks, I just gave that a try (which also meant taking the "withCredentials: true" on my service calls but unfotunately it completely breaks the authentication.